# Apply CSS style to text within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to apply a CSS style within Javascript?

Say I have a CSS style titled "InfoFont" and I want to apply it to the text written from `document.write("Information");`, how would I do this?

Comment: `document.write("<span class='InfoFont'>Information</span>");`, with the normal caveat that `document.write` should be avoided.

Comment: I don't feel like expanding on the better alternatives to document.write though :)

Comment: @MattGreer: +1 for the best comment answer. Post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to wrap the content you are adding dynamically with a tag containing the desired CSS class.

Are you really adding content via `document.write` though?

It would be more common to see something like this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement( "div" );

newDiv.className = "InfoFont";
newDiv.innerHTML = "[YOUR CONTENT HERE]";

document.getElementById( "[RELEVANT CONTAINER ID]" ).appendChild( newDiv );
```

Comment: Don't use `.setAttribute("class")`. There are IE issues. Use `newDiv.className = ...` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need a document element like a span or a div to encapsulate your text.  Then, you can apply a style to the encapsulating element.

As the comment mentioned, you should be avoiding document.write.  I recommend you use jquery or another framework to manipulate the DOM if you have access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.setAttribute('id', 'ELEMENTID');
ele.setAttribute('className', 'InfoFont'); // OR  ele.className = 'InfoFont';
ele.innerHTML = "CONTENT";
```

> **@Matt's comment answer is the simply best answer.**

Comment: _@Matt's comment answer is the simply best answer._ If you leave out the undesirability of using document.write to add content.